# How to Populate An Array of Month Number In jQuery - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/0mj2cxmt/1/) and let me know how I can dynamically populate the number of each month for current year in jQuery or JavaScript?

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var daysInMonth = [];
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();

for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
    daysInMonth.push(d.getMonth());
}
console.log(daysInMonth);
```

Comment: What output do you want? [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] ?

Comment: Hi Sam, the number of days in each month

Comment: So like: October = 31?

Comment: yeah so for example for 2014 would be an array of [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var daysInMonth = [];

for (var i = 0; i < monthNames.length; i++) {
    var year = 2014;
    var month = new Date(monthNames[i] + " 01 "+ year).getMonth() + 1;
    daysInMonth.push(new Date(year, month, 0).getDate());
}
console.log(daysInMonth);
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/0mj2cxmt/7/

Comment: Thanks sam this is exactly what I was looking for but there are some issue here! Feb 2014 has 28 days in but you are getting 31!

Comment: I updated the code, the getMonth() function returns 0 based month number so I forgot to add 1 to that value.

Answer (score 1):

@Sam Battat's answer works too, but for a simple snippet of code that works on any year when called you could try this:

```
var thisDay = new Date();
var thisYear = thisDay.getYear();
var feb29th = new Date(thisYear, 1, 29);
var febDays = ((feb29th.getMonth() === 1) ? 29 : 28);
var dayCounts = [31,febDays,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
```

Notes:

- The number of days is hard coded for all months except February since they don't change
- The `feb29th` variable above will actually become **March 1st** on years that don't have 29 days (e.g. non-leap years) and thus the month won't be "1"... defaulting the number of days back to 28

**Update**:

After running this perf test http://jsperf.com/leap-year-check it has become apparent that the "crafty" check for a leap year performance is nowhere near as good as basic math checks.

Thus I'd consider this to be even more efficient.

```
var thisDay = new Date();
var thisYear = thisDay.getYear();
var febDays = 28;
if((thisYear % 4 == 0) && (thisYear % 100 != 0) || (thisYear % 400 == 0)){
  febDays = 29;
}
var dayCounts = [31,febDays,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
```